# How to specify fallback source for Image component of Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created a component named `Avatar` and it wraps `Image` of **Next.JS**.
The parent component of `Avatar` uses `src` prop (which is a string) to change the image source (this will be a remote source). If it does not specify the `src` prop, then a default local image will be used as shown in the following code snippet.

```
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "./Avatar.module.css";
import AvatarPhoto from "../images/avatar-default.png";

export const Avatar = ({ src, alt, size = 47 }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.imgContainer}>
      <Image
        className={styles.img}
        src={src ?? AvatarPhoto}
        alt={alt}
        width={size}
        height={size}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

What I could not achieved is if the specified source is invalid, how can I show the local image.
For example; if there is not a image in the specified source (If the Get request for the source results with 404 Error), I want to use the default avatar image.

Is there a fallback property of **Next**'s `Image` ?
If not, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#onerror

```
export const Avatar = ({ src, alt, size = 47 }) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={styles.imgContainer}>
      <Image
        className={styles.img}
        src={!error ? src : AvatarPhoto}
        alt={alt}
        width={size}
        height={size}
        onError={() => setError(true)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks it works. But, where did you find onError property? It is not mentioned in the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Comment: Image component underneath is a html `<img />` tag. Every html element has a onload and onerror event listener. Because its javascript, it becomes onError and onLoad @eneski